# Use AVD Manager without Starting Android Studio

Tags: android-emulator

I would like to use the Android Emulator to work on some APKs. In order to start the Android Emulator, based on the instructions here: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html

So, I need to start the AVD Manager from Android Studio, then create a device and start the emulator.

Now, the issue is, when I open Android Studio, it asks me to create a new Project or open an existing one before continuing. This takes a long time. Isn't there a way to just start the AVD Manager without opening the Android Studio GUI?

Probably, there is a way to start AVD Manager from command line?

Thanks.

Comment: Please check my answer here on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42718973/run-avd-emulator-without-android-studio/54994569#54994569

Answer (score 1):

You can navigate to the directory where you have installed SDK and launch "AVD Manager.exe"

Comment: Any clue how to launch AVD manager on Mac? (without using android studio)

Comment: I would like to know as well.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 19.10!

With the environment variables already configured ($ANDROID_HOME), you should be able to list the AVDs, but if you are unable to start the AVD, do the following:

# Check the AVD target name

> emulator -list-avds

# But to start do:

> $ANDROID_HOME/emulator/emulator @avd_name

or

> /home/$USER/Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator @avd_name

Comment: can confirm this works. Launches faster than expected also

Comment: I currently use a shortcut with this same path on Ubuntu 20.04.4. It works!

Comment: My shortcut at Settings >> Keyboard Shortcuts: 
sh -c "$ANDROID_HOME/emulator/emulator @Pixel_2_API_24"