# How to startd the AVD manager without starting android studio

Tags: android-emulator, android-sdk

[Use AVD Manager without Starting Android Studio](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/176903/use-avd-manager-without-starting-android-studio) this question is the same as mine, but the answer does nt work for me. There's no executable to launchd AVD manager on my SDK directory (I'm on ubuntu). Could it be that things changed? The only thing I can find is `/home/lz/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/avdmanager` which is just a command line script, not the GUI that I want to launchd

Answer (score 4):

It is just the `android avd` command, where the `android` shell script is in the tools/ directory of your SDK installation.

Or go to the directory and

```
cd ~/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/ 
./avdmanager
```

Documentation can be found (deprecated) but it works for me
https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/help/android.html

I hope it will be useful

Comment: but it won't launch the GUI. I need the GUI, not the shell application

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs I believe the GUI is part of Android Studio...